# bootstrap v4.5 navbar (with mega menu) from transparent to solid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I'm implementing a navbar mega menu from [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/mega-menu/).

I want the navbar and it's sub-menus not to be transparent.

I changed the code as following:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

 <!-- div container -->
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Navbar brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand text-capitalize" href="{% url 'index' %}">
   <img src="{%static '/img/logo.png' %}" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;" class="logo" alt="">
  </a>

  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent2"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
    
    <!--  some menu items -->        

  </div>
  <!-- Collapsible content -->

 /div>
 <!-- div container -->

</nav>
<!-- Navbar -->
```

I have deleted `bg-light` property and also added this piece:

```
.navbar{
 background-color: red;
}
```

But the `navbar` is still semi-transparent.

I want both the navbar and it's sub-menus to be solid.

how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Add navbar-dark to `nav` tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent2"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent2">

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Man! this property is it's default value. but it's transparent too!!!